# Problema al agregar condición WHERE en consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL:

```
  INSERT INTO GeoVictoria.dbo.metas( id_calendario, id_almacen, cod_almacen, cargo, horas_turno, monto_meta_dia, semana_bono, monto_meta_cargo, total_horas, meta_semanal_tienda)
     SELECT  c.id_calendario, 
        al.id_almacen, 
        u.group_identifier,  
        e.cargo, 
        CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            DATEDIFF(hour, t.start_hour, t.end_hour ) - (t.break_minutes/60) 
        ELSE 
            0
        END
        as horas,
        md.meta_diaria, 
        c.semana_bono,  
        CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN
            (md.meta_diaria / SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, t.start_hour, t.end_hour ) - (t.break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) ) * ( DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) )   
        ELSE 
            md.meta_diaria 
        END as meta,
        SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, t.start_hour, t.end_hour ) - (t.break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) AS total_horas_turno_dia,  
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN e.cargo = 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN md.meta_diaria END) OVER(PARTITION BY c.semana_bono, al.id_almacen), 2) as meta_semanal_tienda 
    FROM usuarios as u 
        INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '') = u.identifier 
        INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
        INNER JOIN turnos as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
        INNER JOIN calendario as c ON c.id_calendario = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9))  
        INNER JOIN almacen as al ON al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier   
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT sum(venta) as meta_diaria 
                        FROM venta as v 
                        WHERE v.id_calendario = SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) AND (v.id_almacen = al.id_almacen) AND v.tipo = 'PPTO' ) AS md 
    WHERE p.begins >= 20190701000000  
          AND p.begins <= 20190731000000  
          AND u.name <> 'ADMINISTRADOR' 
         AND u.enabled = 1 

    ORDER BY begins, group_identifier ASC;
```

Cuando la ejecuto así tal como está todo funciona OK, el problema es que necesito agregarle la condición de que solo debe tomar en cuenta para distribución de metas, aquellos empleados que esten vigentes a través de la condición:

AND e.vigente = 'SI'

Pero cuando agrego dicha condición, me salta el error:

Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error de división entre cero.
Se terminó la instrucción.
Advertencia: valor NULL eliminado por el agregado u otra operación SET.

Se que se produce en alguna de las columnas calculadas, pero no entiendo la razón. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: ¿En dónde agregas la condición?

Comment: @Antonio Veneroso Contreras en el WHERE después de AND u.enabled = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como buena práctica general, te recomiendo que si haces una consulta en que la expresión que está dividiendo es condicional, uses `NULLIF` para ponerte en el caso que esa expresión sea cero.

En tu caso, me da la impresión que la expresión `CASE` que define la columna `meta` es la que lanza el error, y deberías cambiarla por la siguiente:

```
CASE 
    WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' 
    THEN (md.meta_diaria / NULLIF(SUM( CASE WHEN e.cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, t.start_hour, t.end_hour ) - (t.break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) ) * ( DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60),0) )   
    ELSE md.meta_diaria 
END as meta
```